# If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{x_i+2017}=\frac{1}{2017}$ for $x_i>0$, then prove that $\sqrt[2017]{x_1x_2...x_{2017}}\ge2016\cdot2017$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots{},x_{2017}$ be positive reals such that 
>   $$\dfrac{1}{x_1+2017}+\cdots{}+\dfrac{1}{x_{2017}+2017}=\dfrac{1}{2017}.$$
>   **Prove that:** 
>   $$\sqrt[2017]{x_1x_2\cdots{}x_{2017}}\ge2016\cdot{}2017.$$

**Progress:** By the AM-HM inequality, I've managed to show that $$x_1+x_2+\cdots{}+x_{2017}\ge 2017^2(2016).$$
I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem written verbatim. Do you have any progress or hints to tell us about? Are you stuck on this? Is this a challenge?

Comment: Sounds like you can use that HM<=GM<=AM

Comment: This is tagged "context-math" - please let us know the source of the problem.

Comment: When does the contest end?  That is, how soon do you want us to give you the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM $\frac{1}{2017}-\frac{1}{x_i+2017}=\frac{x_i}{2017(x_i+2017)}=\sum\limits_{k\neq i}\frac{1}{x_k+2017}\geq\frac{2016}{\sqrt[2016]{\prod\limits_{k\neq i}(x_k+2017)}}$ and product of these

Comment: $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2017} x_i \ge \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2017} \frac{2016\cdot 2017(x_i+2017)}{\sqrt[2016]{\prod\limits_{k\not =i} (x_k+2017)}}=(2016\cdot 2017)^{2017}$$